# Ternary operator in varargs returning object or array is invalid

Tags: java

This is puzzling me and I would like an explanation.

```
public foo(EventPoint... eventPoints) { 
  //...
}


boolean isThisHappening;

foo(isThisHappening ? new EventPoint() : new EventPoint[]{});
```

Even though `foo(new EventPoint());` is valid and `foo(new EventPoint[]{});` is also valid. Is this the ternary operator failing due to type evaluation?

Using JDK 1.7.0
Getting the error:
  required: EventPoint[]
  found: Object
  reason: argument type Object does not conform to vararg element type EventPoint

Comment: I am getting found java.lang.Object reason argument type does not conform to vararg element type. More specifically they are not of type Object which is causing the problem.

Comment: Post a complete example and provide the version of `javac`. Both `Object` and `Object[]` *are* `Object`s so it sounds strange.

Comment: Your edits turned a bad question into a quite good one ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really going to ask the question since the solution was easy. I just didn't understand the part about a ? b : c having a specific type. Which is obvious when I think about it. Thanks for the great answers aioobe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is this the ternary operator failing?***

The type of a ternary expression is basically the most specific subtype of the two last operands ([JLS Reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)). The most specific subtype of `EventPoint` and `EventPoint[]` is `Object`. If your var-arg method is declared to accept `EventPoint...` it simply won't work.

You should change

```
foo(state == ItemEvent.SELECTED ? (EventPoint) e.getItem()
                                : new EventPoint[]{});
```

to

```
foo(state == ItemEvent.SELECTED ? new EventPoint[] { (EventPoint) e.getItem() }
                                : new EventPoint[] { });
```

and it should compile just fine.

Comment: yep.. you did ;-)  (It is still simplified, since with `Object...` as argument type it still works ;-)  Updated my answer though.

Comment: Or, ditch the ternary operator.

Comment: This is correct. But I don't understand why. Why was one of the parameters being evaluated as Object?

Comment: Because the expression `a ? b : c` *must have a specific type*. The expression needs to be stored in a temporary variable before being passed to the method. Which type should the compiler choose for this variable? Well, the chosen type must be a super type of both `b` and `c`. If you have `EventPoint` and `EventPoint[]` the only type that fits the bill is `Object`. And you can't pass an `Object` to a method that expects `EventPoint...`.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much. You are combining varargs, which isn't supported. You might want to call it like this:

```
foo(isThisHappening? new Object[]{new Object()} : new Object[]{});
```